# How to properly remove water and debris from basement window well?

Tags: windows, well

I was recently washing my house and noticed that a significant amount of water has collected in two of my basement window wells. Unfortunately I cannot simply pump this water out as it is mixed with debris/dead leaves/sand/dirt.

Is there a way to properly remove this water? Perhaps a pump with a filtration system?

Comment: I'd use a wet/dry shop vacuum.

Comment: Will this filter the leaves and (probably) mud?

Comment: It'll suck them up with the water -- but that won't hurt a wet/dry shop vacuum; it's designed  to handle stuff that would destroy a household vacuum.

Comment: I might add that a shovel can also often be useful in situations like these.  ;-)